# Replace or append block of text in file with contest of another file

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk, grep

I have two files:

`super.conf`

```
someconfig=23;
second line;

#blockbegin
dynamicconfig=12
dynamicconfig2=1323
#blockend

otherconfig=12;
```

`input.conf`

```
newdynamicconfig=12;
anothernewline=1234;
```

I want to run a script and have `input.conf` replace the contents between the `#blockbegin` and `#blockend` lines.

I already have this:

```
sed -i -ne '/^#blockbegin/ {p; r input.conf' -e ':a; n; /#blockend/ {p; b}; ba}; p' super.conf
```

It works well but until I change or remove `#blockend` line in `super.conf`, then script replaces all lines after `#blockbegin`.

---

In addition, I want script to replace block **or** if block doesn't exists in `super.conf` append new block with content of `input.conf` to `super.conf`. 
It can be accomplished by remove + append, but how to remove block using sed or other unix command?

Comment: what do you expect to see when you remove the `#blockend`?

Comment: @perreal without `#blockend` script shouldn't change anything. Or in second case append new block (without changing previous content).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written perl one-liner:

```
perl -0777lni -e 'BEGIN{open(F,pop(@ARGV))||die;$b="#blockbegin";$e="#blockend";local $/;$d=<F>;close(F);}s|\n$b(.*)$e\n||s;print;print "\n$b\n",$d,"\n$e\n" if eof;' edited.file input.file
```

Arguments:

`edited.file` - path to updated file
`input.file` - path to file with new content of block

Script first delete block (if find one matching) and next append new block with new content.

Answer (score 1):

Though I gotta question the utility of this scheme -- I tend to favor systems that complain loudly when expectations aren't met instead of being more loosey-goosey like this -- I believe the following script will do what you want.

Theory of operation: It reads in everything up-front, and then emits its output all in one fell swoop.

Assuming you name the file `injector`, call it like `injector input.conf super.conf`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f
#
# Expects to be called with two files. First is the content to inject,
# second is the file to inject into.

FNR == 1 {
    # This switches from "read replacement content" to "read template"
    # at the boundary between reading the first and second files. This
    # will of course do something suprising if you pass more than two
    # files.
    readReplacement = !readReplacement;
}

# Read a line of replacement content.
readReplacement {
    rCount++;
    replacement[rCount] = $0;
    next;
}

# Read a line of template content.
{
    tCount++;
    template[tCount] = $0;
}

# Note the beginning of the replacement area.
/^#blockbegin$/ {
    beginAt = tCount;
}

# Note the end of the replacement area.
/^#blockend$/ {
    endAt = tCount;
}

# Finished reading everything. Process it all.
END {
    if (beginAt && endAt) {
        # Both beginning and ending markers were found; replace what's
        # in the middle of them.
        emitTemplate(1, beginAt);
        emitReplacement();
        emitTemplate(endAt, tCount);
    } else {
        # Didn't find both markers; just append.
        emitTemplate(1, tCount);
        emitReplacement();
    }
}

# Emit the indicated portion of the template to stdout.
function emitTemplate(from, to) {
    for (i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        print template[i];
    }
}

# Emit the replacement text to stdout.
function emitReplacement() {
    for (i = 1; i <= rCount; i++) {
        print replacement[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice work, I'm added answer with equivalent one-line script ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You mean say

```
sed '/^#blockbegin/,/#blockend/d' super.conf
```

Comment: Did you read all of my question? Try this in file with `#blockbegin` and without `#blockend`: it will delete all lines form `#blockbegin` to end of file!

Comment: In that case, how does it know what and how many lines you want to delete.

Comment: In that case it should'n delete anything... It should work like regexp deleting of: `/#blockbegin(.*)#blockend/gsm`